# Set type as an array of any property names from an interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface

```
interface Details {
  id: string;
  groups: Group[];
  name: string;
  total: number;
  open: boolean;
  debug: boolean;
  demo: boolean;
  registered: boolean;
}
```

I then want a type to be an array of any of the property names from the `Details` type.

For example `['total', 'open', 'demo']` would be valid.

I tried

```
type RequiredFields = { [key in Details]?: string };
```

But I get the following TypeScript error.

```
Type 'Details' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
Type 'Details' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(keyof Details)[]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is probably:

```
type RequiredFields = (keyof Details)[];
```

Comment: That's just the one, thank you!